# How to create a single preference with multiple fields?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a "change password" in my application setting that I want the user be able to input 3 text fields (current password, new password, repeat password) and then just click ok button to save the settings. but the problem is I couldn't find (or been able to create) any preference that can show multiple items (in here 3 `EditTextPreference`s).

the below code shows just a textbox when its clicked to edit.

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <EditTextPreference
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:password="true"
        android:defaultValue=""
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:key="example_text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="@string/pref_default_current_password" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

i'm looing for something like:

```
<Group>
        <EditTextPreference
            android:capitalize="none"
            android:password="true"
            android:defaultValue=""
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:key="example_text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:title="@string/pref_default_current_password" />

        <EditTextPreference
            android:capitalize="none"
            android:password="true"
            android:defaultValue=""
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:key="example_text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:title="@string/pref_default_new_password" />

        <EditTextPreference
            android:capitalize="none"
            android:password="true"
            android:defaultValue=""
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:key="example_text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:title="@string/pref_default_repeat_password" />
</Group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom `DialogPreference`. Your approach look flawed to me, you only want a single preference value to be stored in `SharedPreferences`.

Create a class extending `DialogPreference`, return your inflated view `onCreateDialogView()`, and add some logic when the positive button is clicked. You manage as it was a fragment or activity class, just extending `DialogPreference`:

```
public class CustomPreference extends DialogPreference {

    EditText first;
    EditText second;
    EditText third;

    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.three_edit_texts, null);
        first = v.findViewById(...);
        second = v.findViewById(...);
        third = v.findViewById(...);
        return v;
    }

}
```

Then in XML you just add a:

```
<com.your.package.CustomPreference />
```

Comment: your answer seems to be right but as I'm very new to this can you provide an example?

Answer (score -1):

You need to it sequentially on press of submit button.

```
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

editor.putString("key1", "value1");
editor.putString("key2", "value2");
editor.putString("key3", "value3"); 
editor.commit();
```

Or better create shared preferences util to avoid such boiler plate.

Comment: My problem (at least for the moment) is not saving the preferences but forcing user to input multiple textboxes at the same time. imagine first showing the "current password" textbox. when the user submits it what should I do with it? I need the user to fill all three textboxes at the sametime.